# Selecting the post posted the last 30 days

Tags: mysql

Below are two tables: `users` and `posts`. Create a MySQL query to fetch the total number of posts for last 30 days and by the user with email “test@gmail.com”. Also, what kind of index would you add to the `posts` table to make this query work efficiently.

```
    CREATE TABLE "users" (
"id" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
"email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (' id' ),
UNIQUE KEY  `email` ( `email` )
)

CREATE TABLE "posts" (
"id" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id" int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
"message" text NOT NULL,
created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY ( id' )
)
```

For my query I put this

```
Select Count(*)
from posts
left  join users on posts.id=users.id
where created_at > now() INTERVAL 30 day
    and posts.email = "test@gmail.com"
```

Is this correct or am I missing something

Comment: Please paste the actual code instead of an image.

Comment: Brendan McCaffrey I have the actual code above

Comment: You're create tables statements are images. Paste the actual code.

Comment: Brendan McCaffrey ok I put the code now

Answer (score 0):

Since `posts` does not have a column `email`, the query cannot work.  And "-" is missing.  Assuming you meant this:

```
Select  Count(*)
    from  posts AS p
    left join  users AS u  ON p.id=u.id
    where  p.created_at > now() - INTERVAL 30 day
      and  u.email = "test@gmail.com"
```

Then adding this may help:

```
posts:  INDEX(created_at, id)
```

Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see what indexes, if any, it is using.  Be aware that in some cases it is more efficient to scan the table than to use an index.  Hence, Explain may show a table scan when you think an index should have been used.

For example "1 day" is likely to use an index, but "100 day" may not.